# animation not correctly in SDL(C++)?

Tags: c++, animation, sdl, render, sdl-2

I'm trying to use SDL(c++) to produce an animation for a picture(320width, 64height),with 64×64 per frame.

My problem is that my whole picture(320×64) was squeezed in the 64×64 space, instead of shown per frame.

I have an AnimatedSprite class for drawing the animation with the method Draw()

```
AnimatedSprite::Draw(BackBuffer& backbuffer)
{
//set frame width
this->SetFrameWidth(64);

//set x coordinate
this->SetX(frameCoordinateContainer[m_currentFrame-1]);

backbuffer.DrawAnimatedSprite(*this);
}
```

The method DrawAnimatedSprite is like this,

```
void BackBuffer::DrawAnimatedSprite(AnimatedSprite& animatedSprite)
{
SDL_Rect fillRect;
fillRect.x = animatedSprite.GetX();
fillRect.y = animatedSprite.GetY();
fillRect.w = animatedSprite.getFrameWidth();
fillRect.h = animatedSprite.GetHeight();
SDL_RenderCopy(m_pRenderer, animatedSprite.GetTexture()->GetTexture(), 0, &fillRect);
}
```

So anyone got any idea where might be wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is indeed with the way you use [SDL_RenderCopy](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderCopy), but you should provide a srcrect and a dstrect as well, one is the destination you want your image to be rendered at and the other is what part of your texture you want to be rendered there.

For example if your sprite sheet is (320×64) with a sprite size of (64x64) and you want to print the first frame on the screen at coordinates (x, y) of your *fillRect* you should do something like this:

```
SDL_Rect clip;
clip.x = 0;
clip.y = 0;
clip.w = 64;
clip.h = 64;

SDL_Rect fillRect;
fillRect.x = animatedSprite.GetX();
fillRect.y = animatedSprite.GetY();
fillRect.w = animatedSprite.getFrameWidth();
fillRect.h = animatedSprite.GetHeight();

SDL_RenderCopy(m_pRenderer, animatedSprite.GetTexture()->GetTexture(), &clip, &fillRect);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

[`SDL_RenderCopy`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderCopy):

```
int SDL_RenderCopy(SDL_Renderer*   renderer,
                   SDL_Texture*    texture,
                   const SDL_Rect* srcrect,
                   const SDL_Rect* dstrect)
```

You're passing `fillRect` to `dstrect`, not `srcrect`.

Comment: Sorry that I don't quite understand, so how should I improve it? @LogicStuff

Comment: Try swapping `0` with `&fillRect`.

Comment: I swap `0` with `&fillRect`, but then there will be nothing there. @LogicStuff